# Stuck on Implementation

Tags: c++, implementation

I have to make an implementation for the string operator below

```
String operator +=(const String &str); // this is my declaration which is in my header file
```

The goal is to return a string formed by appending the passed String with the String the method is called on.

This is my code/implementation so far but it has errors and I'm stuck.

```
String::String::operator +=(const String &str)
{
   strcat(contents, str.contents);
   len += str.len;
}
```

How can I fix this? The two error are the first 'String' and the 'operator'

This is the error for the operator: The declaration is incompatible with "String String::operator+=(const String &str)"

and the one for String; explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)

Comment: I'd start with an understanding of what [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) does

Comment: should be: `String String::operator +=`?

Comment: Well for the implementation, it said that it needs a return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the `String` that the operator is called on. It is a compound operator (a mix of the `+` and `=` operators), so you need to return a reference to the `String` that was modified:

```
String& operator +=(const String &str);
```

```
String& String::operator +=(const String &str)
{
    strcat(contents, str.contents);
    len += str.len;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem:

```
String::String::operator +=(const String &str)
      ^^
```

The two marked characters should be replaced by a space, so that you have a return type:

```
String String::operator +=(const String &str)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I guess that the syntactic error when there is a `strcat` without any check or allocation for the resulting string in case it's too short can be considered minor :)

Comment: You mean *semantic* error.  It wasn't obvious whether `strcat` was a class member that handles reallocation or not, so I didn't mention it.  This question was mainly about being confused by compiler errors.